# Read Excel File with POI without header

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i want to reader excel file using poi without title header, my expected result this
[image: expected read excel file]

this is my code

```
public String processExcel(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "excelfile", required = false) MultipartFile excelfile, HttpSession session) {        

        try {
            List<UserRegistrationDetail> lstUser = new ArrayList<>();

            Workbook workbook = null;

            if (excelfile.getOriginalFilename().endsWith("xlsx")) {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelfile.getInputStream());
            } else if (excelfile.getOriginalFilename().endsWith("xls")) {
                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excelfile.getInputStream());
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("msg", new IllegalArgumentException("The specified file is not Excel file"));
            }

            Sheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


        Iterator<Row> iterator = worksheet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
            UserRegistrationDetail user = new UserRegistrationDetail();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell nextCell = cellIterator.next();
                int columnIndex = nextCell.getColumnIndex();

                switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    user.setId(String.valueOf(nextCell.getNumericCellValue()));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    user.setEmail(nextCell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    user.setFullname(nextCell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                }

            }
            lstUser.add(user);
        }
        model.addAttribute("listUser", lstUser);
        session.setAttribute("listUserImport", lstUser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", e.getMessage());
    }

    return "reportregistrationuser";    
}
```

currently my code only read file excel like this
[image: currently read file]

how to implementation my expected result, what am i doing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before you are iterating over every rows, move iterator initially to the 2nd row using `iterator.next()`.
So in your **while** loop, it will start from the 2nd row.

```
Iterator<Row> iterator = worksheet.iterator();
//Add the below line 
 Row headerRow= iterator.next();
```